# SharePoint 2010 Where in SQL are Document Library Items Stored

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know what Database and what table in SQL the files that are uploaded to Document Libraries are stored? I've looked everywhere within SQL and I cannot find them anywhere. I am trying to pull the document out of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to access the SharePoint content database directly. The structure and behavior of those tables are subject to change without notice.

More importantly, there are three APIs to access this data. These APIs are *not* subject to change.

Comment: Could you provide links or names of what those three APIs are?

Comment: Start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147178%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The question is 3-year-old but for historical purposes here's the answer:
[Where are Document Library Items Stored in db?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/192349/59550)

**They are stored in** `[AllLists]` **table.**

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [tp_Title]  
  FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[AllLists] where [tp_BaseType] = 1
```

DatabaseName = Your Database Name

SchemaName = basically, this is [dbo]

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the AllDocs table, is that what you're looking for?

...there's a trick to this, you have content databases labeled Sharepoint_[contentname]_content.  I'm not aware of a way to get at all of the documents at once without using unions depending on your sharepoint implementation.